# How to set apache to rewrite anything after a file extention to the filename itself?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, trailing-slash

How can I set in httpd.conf so that any request to any filename.php/xyz should be redirected to filename.php or at least send an 404 Error.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo